# Is it possible to set a new entity directly from twig?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony2-voter

Sometime i need to check if an user can comment from a **voter**, obviously at this point of the code the comment does not yet exist, but still i need to check if the user is allowed to comment or not.

From the controller i would usually do `$this->isGranted('create', new Comment())` but how i'm supposed to do the same thing in twig? I can't find a clear explaination, and i obviously can't do something like `{% if is_granted('create', new comment()) %}`.

Is there a way to do this without hacking an object from the controller such as rendering a `new Comment()` from the controller? Doing so will allow me to avoid a lot of spaghetti code in my voters.

Comment: You can extend twig with `TwigSimple_Function` that does that, you need to be able to pass whatever `$this` as object is towards the function then

Comment: Might be easier to just pass a new comment to your your twig template.  Or do the check in the controller and pass the results as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can extend twig with `Symfony Twig Extensions`

Look at this documentation link:

[Symfony Twig Extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html)

Inside your twig you can use `is_granted` like this:

```
{{ is_granted(role, object = null, field = null) }}
```